# Google chrome auto refresh

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

When I try to load a page in Google Chrome without Wi-Fi and then turn on Wi-Fi the page refreshes automatically.

I do not want this because I don't have time to turn on a VPN before the page loads.

How do I prevent this?

[*This is not tab discarding. Sorry to anyone who misunderstood the question.*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/281048/#comment-353614)

Comment: I believe it only does this for the first page yes and not all the tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32718801/476909), it seems like setting Chrome's "Offline Auto-Reload Mode" flag to "disabled" should do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually Tab Discarding...

You can take a look here chrome://discards/

If you want to disable then go to chrome://flags, and disable this flag: #automatic-tab-discarding

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/huyGBMWpM4w

Comment: No, it is not tab discarding. What will happen is that I will visit a webpage without internet access, and Chrome will display a page saying "You are offline" or whatever. Then when your internet comes back up, **Chrome will automatically refresh the page**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to my first answer I think I have a little more clarity, so you may want to do both.

If you want to disable then go to chrome://flags, and disable this flag: #enable-offline-auto-reload